# Functional determinant in scalar QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, path-integral, propagator, functional-determinants

I'm trying to integrate out the scalars from the path integral in scalar QED, but I encountered an integral I don't know how to do. The model is

$S = \int_{\mathbb{R}^4}d^4x \left( -\frac{(F_{\mu\nu})^2}{4} + \frac{|D_\mu\Phi|^2}{2} + \frac{\lambda}{4}|\Phi|^4 \right) \ , \quad D_\mu = \partial_\mu + igA_\mu \ .$

The first thing I do is to expand around a classical scalar (which doesn't break Lorentz invariance)

$\Phi = \delta\Phi \ , \quad \bar{\Phi} = \delta\bar{\Phi} \ , \quad |\Phi|^2 = |\Phi|^2_{cl} + \delta\bar{\Phi}\delta\Phi \ , \quad |\delta\Phi|, |\delta\bar{\Phi}| \ll 1 \ .$

Now I only keep terms that are quadratic in the quantum fluctuations $\delta\Phi \ , \delta\bar{\Phi}$, and then integrate them out from the path integral (keeping $A_\mu$ constant, working in the Lorentz gauge $\partial_\mu A^\mu = 0$, and performing some partial integrations)

$Z = \int\mathcal{D}A_\mu\exp \left[ \int_{\mathbb{R}^4}d^4x \left( \frac{(F_{\mu\nu})^2}{4} - \frac{g^2}{2}A_\mu^2|\Phi|^2_{cl} - \frac{\lambda}{4}|\Phi|^4_{cl} \right) \right] Z_\phi \ ,$

$Z_\phi = \int\mathcal{D}\delta\bar{\Phi}\mathcal{D}\delta\Phi\exp \left( -\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}d^4x \delta\bar{\Phi} \left( -\frac{\partial^2 -2igA_\mu\partial^\mu + \lambda|\Phi|^2_{cl}}{2} \right) \delta\Phi \right) \\
\propto \exp \left[ -\text{tr}\log(\partial^2 -2igA_\mu\partial^\mu + \lambda|\Phi|^2_{cl}) \right] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^4}d^4x I$

$I = \int_{\mathbb{R}^4}\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\log G(k)$

The momentum space propagator $G(k)$ is found from a Fourier transform (w.r.t. (x - y)) of the following equation (we also completed a square after the Fourier transform)

$(\partial^2 -2igA_\mu\partial^\mu + \lambda|\Phi|^2_{cl})\Delta(x - y) = \delta(x - y) \quad\Rightarrow\quad G(k) = \frac{1}{(k_\mu + gA_\mu)^2 + \lambda|\Phi|^2_{cl}} \ .$

This yields the following integral:

$I = \int_{\mathbb{R}^4}\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\log \left[ (k_\mu + gA_\mu)^2 + \lambda|\Phi|^2_{cl} \right] \ .$

This is the integral that I'm unsure how to do, and I would prefer it if it's done with a momentum space cutoff $|k| < \Lambda \ , \Lambda \gg 1$. I'm grateful for all the help.

Comment: Unless $A_\mu$ is independent of position, your Fourier transform is incorrect. As far as I know, only fields with constant $F_{\mu\nu}$ have exactly evaluatable functional determinants.

Comment: Maybe this is the error, but I thought I could treat $A_\mu$ as a constant when integrating out the scalars.

Comment: No, you need to compute the functional determinat of $(\partial-ieA)^2-\phi^2$  This is the product of the eigenvalues, so you have to compute the spectrum of this differential operator. This depends on the whole function $A(x)$  . For example, in a constant $F_{\mu\nu}$ this is the Landau level problem. There is  no closed-form solution for the determinant.

Comment: I agree with what you said. Is there any approximation that I can do here, where the first term in this approximation is $A_\mu$ being constant? If so, what I wrote in my original post is still valid, but only to the first order in this approximation.

Comment: @mikestone with regards to your first comment: no, on two counts. Firstly if $A$ is constant, $F$ is vanishing; if $F$ is constant, $A$ is non-vanishing. Secondly, recall the famous calculation in 2-dimensional QED (also known as the Schwinger model). There, the fermion is integrated out exactly, leading to a mass term for the $U(1)$ gauge field.

Comment: @ alexavanitakis. Yes. The masless fermion Schwinger model is the only case   I know one can exactly integrate out the fermions.  I used the resulting quadratic  functional in my PhD thesis in 1977.  For some reason (43 years?) I had forgotten this case. But there is no closed form functional for 4d scalar QED.

Comment: If I can keep the fermion constant in the Schwinger model, I should be able to keep the gauge field constant in scalar QED. I don't see the difference. And the closed form functional for scalar QED is exactly what 'm trying to find, and I'm one integral away from it, which is $I$ in my original post.


I should also mention that $I$ is independent of $A_\mu$ if I use dimensional regularization (since I can then shift $k_\mu \rightarrow k_\mu - gA_\mu$), but this is a bit weird I think, hence I want to regularize with a momentum cutoff instead.